# Full screen Phase Scope? 

Tags: phase

I have to record a phase scope to video. please, offer for a program that you can do a full screen, or what i can zoom in? it doesnt matter its stand alone, or plug-in.
i find one app: http://www.music-sound-lab.com/images/stereotool.jpg, but its to small on the screen.

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a demo of Izotope 5 with new Meter Bridge in full screen mode. Has a phase meter amongst overs you can view in full screen.

Comment: THX awesome! :D

Answer (score 0):

Or if you screen capture in hd quality, and then zoom in with some video editing app.

Answer (score 0):

thx guys, heres the result :)
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFL3j60BKgk&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Nice work! Love Aphrx Twin so that was a treat ;)

Comment: Aphew Twin, even! Damn iPhone keyboard lol